# Matlab Label Points on Map

Tags: matlab, dictionary, label, geo, points

I have Matlab code that looks like this below, and I get a nice plot of colored points based on my input file and variable "prod", which is a 10 x 1 variable but could be `prod = rand(10,1)` for this example.  "lat" and "lont" are latitude and longitude values.  I'm trying to plot a legend that shows all 10 entries with the text file that contains all 10 entries.  With the code that I've shown below, I  get a legend that gives me 1 of the 10 entries with a corresponding color point on the map but with a warning about ignoring "extra" legend entries.  I've searched the documentation and internet for examples of plotting using `scatterm` with a large (my actual data is >100 points) legend but cannot find anything that works.  Thanks in advance for your help!

```
prod = xlsread('J:\out.rms.err.xlsx', 'sheet1','C2:E182'); %open file
disp('finished reading input file');
[txt txt ] = xlsread('J:\out.rms.err.xlsx'); %
text = txt(2:end,1); %farms only
%figure; ax = worldmap({'Spain'});
lat = prod(:,2);
lon = prod(:,3); 
%xy = [ lat lon ];
colormap('hot');
ax = figure(1);
%ax = worldmap([40 45 ], [-11 5]); %Northern Spain
%ax = worldmap([35 40 ], [-11 5]); %Southern Spain
ax = worldmap([35 45 ], [-12 5] );
set(ax,'visible','off','units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
land = shaperead('landareas.shp','UseGeoCoords',true);
geoshow(ax,land,'FaceColor', [0.15 0.5 0.15]);
colormap('hsv');
colorbar;
hold on;
hh = num2str(prod(:,1));
h(1) = scatterm(ax,lat,lon,20,prod(:,1),'filled');
legend(h,text,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`scatterm` produces a graph that belong to the Scatter Series. With this type of graph, only one symbol can be used (one marker) and the default type is a circle (`'o'`). The legend corresponds to this unique symbol.

You can however bypass this limitation by either (i) **overlaying several graphs** having only one point each, or (ii) **create your own legend** using `patch` for example (the legend is therefore disconnected from the data - to be used only as a final graphical illustration)